# how to update gorm session object

Tags: mongodb, grails

let say two domain class

```
class A {
...
static hasMany= [b:B]
}
class B {
boolean status = false
static belongsTo=[a:A]
}
```

when  query

```
a.b.status
```

the result is [false, false , false ]

now

```
b.status = ture`
     b.save()
```

whan query `a.status`

the result is [false, false , false ]
it shoult be [false, false, true]

the result come from session object, so how can i update session oject of domain class a, databse used mongodb

Comment: Not quite sure, long time since I had this problem but I think I solved it by doing (in your case) b.merge() or b.refresh() - http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/merge.html - BIIIG note: I'm not that sure this is what'll help you here.

Answer (score 0):

change `b.save()` to `b.save(flush:true)`